# Text NOT wrapping around floating div

Tags: css

I am a bit confused about why the text does not float around floating div.Here's an example:

```css
#placeholder {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 113px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<p>DIRECTIONS<br> Preheat oven to 400°F. Line a muffin tin. Set aside. In a stand mixer fitted with a paddle attachment, cream together butter and sugar until light and fluffy. Meanwhile, using a blender, puree the diced pears, milk, and almond extract until
  smooth.</p>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Is it because the floating div is the last element? Can I somehow achieve this but preserving the floating div as the last element? Thanks!

Comment: fix your question, and provide your code. Thanks

Comment: Why is it not possible to re-arrange the order? It is faster that way

Comment: What is that placeholder suppose to show  (texte/picture or both ? What is the parent structure of your <p> ? can you add a class or an id to that <p>?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this? I just re-arranged the order of the two elements. Yours does not work because `p` has already occupied the whole width before the floating element appeared

```css
#placeholder {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 113px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<p>DIRECTIONS<br> Preheat oven to 400°F. Line a muffin tin. Set aside. In a stand mixer fitted with a paddle attachment, cream together butter and sugar until light and fluffy. Meanwhile, using a blender, puree the diced pears, milk, and almond extract until
  smooth.</p>
```

Or if you really want to preserve the order, add `float:right` and `width:87.5%` to the `p` element. The `87.5%` came from subtracting the width of the floating div to the default width of the `p` element *(which is `100%`)*

```css
p {
  float: right;
  width:87.5%;
}

#placeholder {
  float: left;
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 113px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<p>DIRECTIONS<br> Preheat oven to 400°F. Line a muffin tin. Set aside. In a stand mixer fitted with a paddle attachment, cream together butter and sugar until light and fluffy. Meanwhile, using a blender, puree the diced pears, milk, and almond extract until
  smooth.
</p>
```

**Note:** It is best to add `clear:both` to the next element after the floating div to avoid placement complications